# Import Quartz DLL in C# VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I'm in need for the Quartz DLL , I've downloaded all the source and everything and there is the Quartz.dll and Common.Logging.dll files, but I don't know how to use them in my own applications.

Can someone tell me how to do this, it's just this one step that's stopping me from doing it all.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandeep,

Don't mind discussing this with you, but would need to know what the application is that you are trying to use the Quartz library for.  Unfortunately, the Quartz library documentation isn't quite what it should be, and it took several days for me to absorb the product myself.

The jest of using it is something like the following:

1. Create a SchedulerFactory
2. Create a Scheduler
3. Create a JobDetail
4. Create a Trigger
5. schedule the job (with the detail and the trigger)

From there, everything else is all in the details on the task you are trying to accomplish.  Can't give any more specifics without that info.  Hope that 30 second lesson gets you on your way.

Comment: I'm creating a utility which will allow the user to do certain actions at a certain time or date.

Unless you know a way to access Task Scheduler via code rather that the command line?

I'm just confused on how to import the dll to actually get the methods to work.

Comment: in your project, add reference.  Not sure how much more I can go into than that.... your tasks are programmed as an implementation of an IJob, and other than that, everything gets done like the 5 steps I outlined.

There are methods that you can get Task Scheduler, via command line, to setup tasks to run your exe's, but I found it easier to use the Quartz library.  If you're looking for some consulting work, please do send me a message, and we can work something out.

again, it's all in the details you provide Sandeep.

Comment: Thanks for the info Richard. I've only started programming in C# and although I am liking it a lot, it's just I can't figure things out like referencing and importing libraries etc.

Would you be able to include a code snippet on how I would be able to use the Quartz library methods in my code.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html should get you started.  Start with a sample project and try out what you want to do there, and after you understand how to do what you want to do, you can then write the implementation in your actual project.  Referencing in visual studio is under "Solution Explorer", look at your project, and there's an entry called "References"  You can right-click and "Add a reference" to the project.